# Removing @ mentions from pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I am working on a thesis project on smartworking. I downloaded some tweets using Python and I wanted to get rid of users / mentions before implementing wordclouds. However, I can't delete the users, but with the commands shown I delete only the "@".

```
df['token']=df['token'].apply(lambda x:re.sub(r"@mention","", x))
df['token']=df['token'].apply(lambda x:re.sub(r"@[A-Za-z0-9]+","", x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code should work, however for efficiency use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['token2'] = df['token'].str.replace('@[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?', '', regex=True)
# or for [a-zA-Z0-9_] use \w
# df['token2'] = df['token'].str.replace('@\w+\s?', '', regex=True)
```

example:

```
                  token          token2
0  this is a @test case  this is a case
```